# How do I pass a string name to another bash script? I want it as a text name, not as variable name

Tags: string

./change_date_2_4_new.sh -v year4=$year4 -v month4=$month4 -v day4=$day4 -v time4=$time4 -v year2=$year2 -v month2=$month2 -v day2=$day2 -v time2=$time2 -v year3=$year3 -v month3=$month3 -v day3=$day3 -v time3=$time3 -v namelist=$'namelist.input'

Every variable which is an integer value (all but the last) are passed correctly.  The string name "namelist.input" appears as a blank in an echo statement in the second script.

Comment: what does the script display if you place the following in the script (just before where you process your input parameters): `echo $*`; how is the script parsing the input parameters?

Comment: Hello:  That statement, when copied as is, does not produce any output.  However, if I echo namelist before making the call to the second script, it prints out fine.